# javascript exclude "00" and "01" strings

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have an array of 2char strings. I need to console.log only the ones that are different from "00" and "01"

I've been told that the following code, skips the "00" strings but i don't understand how it works, so i can't modify it to skip the "01" strings too:

```
if (!/^0+$/.test(onestring)) continue;
```

My code:

```
var ar = ["a3","00","12","01","ab","7f"];

for (var i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
      if (!/^0+$/.test(ar[i])) console.log(ar[i]);    
}
```

I don't understand exactly what `/^0+$/` does and how it can be modified to include "01" too.

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/hufalinitela/1/edit?js,console,output)

Comment: In regex, `+` means "one or more".  So `/^0+$/` matches a string consisting of at least one zero (`^` means "start of string" and `$` means "end of string").

Comment: Do you *need* to use a regex here?

Comment: to include `01` too you could change it to `/^0+1?$/` ... if you want any single digit number with one or more 0s in front you could do `/^0+\d?$/`

Comment: @smerny has the correct answer. For further reading on this aspect of regular expressions: [RegExp quantifiers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#quantifiers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a regular expression and will match each string consisting of one or more zeros.

Depending on what you intend to do, here are some expressions:

1. **Match any string starting with `00` or `01`:** 

   `if (!/^0[01]/.test(somestring))`

   Match Examples: 

    - `00`

    - `01`

    - `00xxxx`

    - `01xxxx`
2. **Match only `00` and `01`:**

   `if (!/^0[01]$/.test(somestring))`
3. **Match `0`, `00` and `01`:**

    `if (!/^0[01]?$/.test(somestring))`

Comment: It should match `00` - actually it matches any string starting with either `00` or `01`

Comment: @smerny true, `+`is not really necessary, changed it.

Comment: @shawnb `/^0+1?$/` would match everything starting with at least one zero and ending with zero or one. Something like `0021` wouldn't match..

Comment: @agim, yea, the reason i posted that was because it most closely matches the OP's original format. if `00` is matched by `0+`, I assumed `01` should work the same in the case.

Comment: @agim Oh yeah, I missed that it is only supposed to match (and test, I guess) two character strings

Comment: @smerny the original expression would also match more than two strings, namely `0`, `00`, `00000...`
If you want a full match only for i.e. 00 and 01, then you should change it to `if (!/^0[01]$/.test(somestring))`.

To match also a `0` use `if (!/^0[01]?$/.test(somestring))` - this will match `0`, `00` and `01`

Comment: @agim I'm guessing this is way simpler than we've made it and Aitor should go with /^0[01]$/

Comment: I don't think accepting preceding 0's would be a problem especially considering the use in the OP, but your answer should be fine if you add the `$` assuming there never are preceding 0's that should still match